# AzureAD, Client confidential app calling webapi with a custom Application ID URI, returns 401

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I'm trying to develop an API which can be called from different web apps.

If I call the api with a client confidential app, using the default scope (api://[APIclientId]/.default), everything works.

But If I specify a custom Application ID URI for the API app registration (like: api://myapi.iss.it), and I set the scope to api://myapi.iss.it/.default, I get HTTP401 from the webapp.

This is the method to retrieve the token for the webapp to call the api:

```
    private async Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication app;
        string AURY = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _config["AzureAd:Instance"] + "{0}", _config["AzureAd:TenantId"]);
        app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_config["AzureAd:ClientId"])
            .WithClientSecret(_config["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(AURY))
            .Build();
        var accessToken = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { _config["API:scope"] }).ExecuteAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("token: " + accessToken.AccessToken);
        //var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForAppAsync(_TodoListScope);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.AccessToken);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
```

I notice that the Audience is still api://[APIclientId] in the token, even if I set the api:scope to api://myapi.iss.it/.default

Is it correct?
any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution on the Microsoft Q&A platform.

Basically, I didn't specifiy the Audience in the API application, so by default it was "api://[APIclientId]".
When the API was verifing the token of the app (where the aud was api://myapi.iss.it), the exception "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException" was raised, and the API returned 401.

If you have the same problem, and you are using the Microsoft.Indentity.Web library, specifying the Audience in the appsetting.json may be enough.